# Angular 2+ Observable retryWhen unit test

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I am trying to unit test a function that returns an observable with `retryWhen`. I am able to test that if the error is different from 401, 403 or 500 I finally end up by throwing an error, but I don't know how to check that there has been 10 retries.

```
this.http.post(keepAliveUrl, {refreshToken: token.refreshToken} , options)
      .map(response => {
        return this.save(new Token(response.json()));
      })
      .retryWhen((errors) => {
        let errorCount = 0;
        return errors
          .mergeMap((error) => {
            if (errorCount >= 10 || error.status === 401 || error.status === 403 || error.status === 500) {
              return this.errorService.handleObservableError(error, 'token.service - refresh');
            } else {
              errorCount ++;
              return Observable.of(error);
            }
          });
      });
```

Unit test

```
it('[other error] => retry', fakeAsync(() => {
    let result: Token;
    let catchedError: any;

    this.tokenService.refresh(token)
      .subscribe(
        (token: Token) => result = token,
        (error: Error) => catchedError = error
      );

    tick();

    this.lastConnection.mockError(mockError({
      status: 409,
      statusText: 'Conflict',
    }));

    tick();

    expect(result).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(catchedError).toBeDefined();
  }));
```